# How can I trigger Windows Update on a large number of servers without special tools

Tags: automation, windows-update

We have a large number of Windows Server 2012 VMs that need monthly updates, but the updates have to happen in a scheduled downtime window. That means we can't just configure the servers to install updates automatically.

Triggering the updates and reboots manually is a lot of work. We don't have SCCM. Is there a way to trigger windows update on a large number of servers without any special tools?

Comment: You might start by checking this thread : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16180265/automatically-update-windows-fully

Comment: Thanks, I missed that one in my search. I'll check it out!